# How to sort String from alphabet first then number (in javascript). example if the input is "asd5lk43fj6vc" and the output should be "acdfjklsv3456"

Tags: javascript, sorting, split

I'm working on a simple sorting program where i need to sort an input from a user to remove whitespace, special character and sort the string(from user input) ascendingly. im new to learning js and i found this code online.

```
let sortNumButton = document.getElementById('sortNumButton');
let sortOutputContainer = document.getElementById('sortOutputContainer');
let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');

sortNumButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
let paragraph = document.createElement('p')

paragraph.innerText = inputField.value.split('').sort().join('').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-. ]/g, "");
sortOutputContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
inputField.value = "";
})
```

the program works but the output prints the number first, not alphabet first

Answer (score 0):

You can `.replace` the result afterwards, matching numeric characters and putting that capture group at the end instead of the beginning.

```js
const inputValue = "asd5lk43fj6vc";
const sorted = [...inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-. ]/g, '')].sort().join('');
const result = sorted.replace(/^(\d+)(.*)/, '$2$1');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) for numbers and sort then the rest by their value.

```js
const
    sort = string => string
        .split('')
        .sort((a, b) => isFinite(a) - isFinite(b) || a > b || -(a < b))
        .join('');

console.log(sort('asd5lk43fj6vc'));
```